# Typing an array of generics, and later merging them together

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a react component that takes as children different query components, and runs them concurrently, a bit like `promise.all`. The final child is a function that gets all the query results once they are finished.
e.g

```
<GroupedQueries>
  <QueryComp<UserQueryResult> query={getUsers} />
  <QueryComp<AccountsQueryResult> query={getAccounts} />

  {(user, account) => {
    if (user.loading || accounts.loading) {
      return <Spinner />;
    }
    // Want to do stuff with here with typed user & account
    // user:UserQueryResult and account: AccountsQueryResult
    
  }}
</GroupedQueries>
```

This is my feeble attempt:

```
interface GroupedQueriesProps<TData> { // Probably wrong, need an array of generics
      children: Array<QueryComp<TData>> | ((result: ????) => React.ReactNode);
}
```

Is this possible?